# Does Orlah apply to hydroponic grown trees

Tags: halacha, agriculture, trees, yoreh-deah, orla-revai

Apparently [it is possible to grow trees in hydroponic systems](https://brightlanegardens.com/grow-trees-hydroponic-system/). I am curious, according to Halacha would fruit grown from hydroponic grown trees be subject to the laws of Orlah? Or since they are not growing from the earth’s ground, is it similar to Shemitta where it doesn’t apply?

Comment: I really like this question! I don't have the time to dive into this right now, but if you want a starting point for research in classical sources (Mishnah, Talmud) try "עציץ שאינו נקוב." Sometimes halacha differentiates between a flowerpot (עציץ) that has a hole in the base (i.e., נקוב) and one that does not have a hole (אינו נקוב). The dirt in the pots with holes can be considered to be attached to the ground by roots that grow through the holes. It's likely that parallels can be drawn between the un-hole-y pots and hydroponics systems.

Comment: An atzitz sheino nakuv is orlah mdrabanan ,and some say even M’drabanan it isn't. However ,it is a whole question if it was taken out and placed in dirt when does the orlah clock start...